# Qt get combobox currentIndex from another class(out of ui class)

Tags: c++, qt, combobox

I want to get the currentIndex of combobox in the main Widget, then send this value to another class. I tried to make a function to return the currentIndex, however, I always get '0'. Could someone explain me why, or give me an example? Plus, I think it's because I create a new object in another class, but how can I get the actived Widget's pointer? Here are the codes:

widget.h

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui { class Widget; }

class Widget : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();
    int comboboxText();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::Widget *ui; };

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

widget.cpp

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include "database.h"

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}

int Widget::comboboxText(){
    return ui->comboBox->currentIndex();
}

void Widget::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    qDebug() << "from Widget: " << comboboxText();
    Database database;
    database.getIndex();
}
```

database.h

```
#ifndef DATABASE_H
#define DATABASE_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>

class Database : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Database(QObject *parent = 0);
    void getIndex();

signals:

public slots:
};

#endif // DATABASE_H
```

database.cpp

```
#include "database.h"
#include <widget.h>

Database::Database(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

void Database::getIndex(){
    Widget a;
    qDebug()<< "from database: " << a.comboboxText();

}
```

Comment: Yes, it is because you are creating a new object. In order to deal with the same object, you need to pass a pointer to your `Widget` to the `Database` object (maybe in the constructor). and use that pointer to call `comboboxText` instead of calling it on a new object.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. Could you give me an example how to pass that pointer? I am not really know the way.